# jQuery datepicker - setting date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

On the screen there are start date datepickers and corresponding end date datepickers.

When a user selects a start date from one of many datepickers, I want to set the corresponding end date.  The end date should be the start date + 1 year.

My code works, but I'm not sure its *really* setting the end date.  It is putting the correct date value into the end date datepicker text field.  But when you *open* the calendar it just shows todays date selected and *not* the actual date that was entered via the code.

EDIT: Its like there is 2 calendars - the user can click in the textbox to open the calendar, or click on a calendar icon to open the calendar.  If the date is set in code and they click on the textbox to opent he calendar - it shows the date selected ok.  But if they click on the icon to open the calendar, its like the date is not there..

Is there any issues here?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.input-group.date').change(function() {
            var $input = $(this).find('input.form-control');


            var effdateid = $input.attr('id');

//have they selected an input date?
            if (effdateid.toLowerCase().indexOf("effective") >= 0){
                var expdateid = effdateid.replace("effective", "expire");

//get the input date and add a year
            var myDate = new Date($input.val());
            myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + 1);

//set the end date if its blank
            if (!$("#" + expdateid).val()) {
                var $datepicker = $("#" + expdateid);
                $datepicker.datepicker();
                $datepicker.datepicker('setDate', new Date(myDate));
            }
        }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

this should work

```
document.getElementById("datePicker").valueAsDate = new Date()
```

Comment: there is nothing called datePicker in my HTML

Comment: its about valueAsDate

Comment: didnt work I tried document.getElementById("#" + expdateid).valueAsDate = new Date(myDate)